# Mapping a UNC source as a drive

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When I run scripts from inside a .CMD file, %~dp0 will get the current/working directory. It is aware of UNC paths. However, I have several scripts on three flash drives, five different portable drives, and three different file servers. I'd like to be able to write one script to run on all of them.

How can I use the script to look at "%~dp0", determine if is on a UNC source and if the source is UNC then map a drive, otherwise just run?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to check if the drive is mapped -

```
net use %~d0 2>nul >nul || echo drive not mapped & goto :run
```

`2>nul >nul` redirects both stdout and stderr to nul.

The command(s) after `||` will only run if an error level is set by the net use command.

If you want to check if the drive is on a remote server, but not mapped, then map the drive -

```
if "%~d0"=="\\" for /f %%D in (R S T U V W X Y Z) do if not exist %%D:\ (
    net use %%D: %~dp0 >nul
    set path=%%D:
    goto :run
)

:run
```

`%~d0` will equal `\\` if the script is being run remotely, but the path has not already been mapped.

Loops through `R S T U V W X Y Z` (unlikely to all be mapped - you can add / remove letters) checking if they *are* already mapped. If they are not, map the path to that drive letter and continue with the script

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    ( call :ensureMappedRun %* )|| exit /b 

    rem This line is reached when :ensureMappedRun finishes with errorlevel=0
    rem meaning the batch file is not being executed from a UNC path
    
    echo running "%~f0" %*
    pause
    
    endlocal
    exit /b 0
    
:ensureMappedRun
    rem test if current context is "drive:...."
    echo %~f0 | findstr /r /i /b /c:"[a-z]:" >nul 2>nul
    if not errorlevel 1 exit /b 0

    rem Running from UNC path. Map to drive letter
    pushd "\\%~p0"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo ERROR : UNC path not accesible or no drive letters available
        pause
        exit
    )
    
    rem Restart the current batch file from the new drive\path
    call "%cd%\%~nx0" %*

    rem Clean the drive assignment
    popd
    
    rem And return, signaling the batch has been run redirected
    exit /b 1
```